# Join Plugin for pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Are there any plugins which provide [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) features for piplines? I have n pipeline jobs which should trigger ONE freestyle job. Therefore the trigger process has to wait until all pipeline jobs are finished.

[image: Scenario]

This is exactly what the Join Plugin provides. But only for Freestyle jobs. I could trigger a "trigger freestyle job" after each pipeline job, but this seems some kind of dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) which fits my needs. But unfortunately it can't be used for Pipeline Jobs. But still this plugin is very usefull!